# tinyscrollbar scroll not working in chrome in windows 8.0

Tags: jquery

I have machine with chrome installed on Windows 8.0 laptop (which has touchscreen)
I have implemented tinyscrollbar in my web application.
The tinyscrollbar shows and scrolls when application opened in Mozilla.
But in chrome it is having issues , scrollbar displays but scroll functionality is not working
I found that "ontouchstart" in windows property returns a true value.
Has this got anything to do with scroll not working ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Windows 8 machine running it on Chrome.

There is a problem with `if(hasTouchEvents)` statement. You will only enter into `if(hasTouchEvents)` on Chrome and it will never initialize the binding of `thumb` and `mouseevents`. So if you want to attach the mouse events and drag to the track you must comment out the else statement in v2.1.8 of the plugin to:

```
else
{
    $thumb.bind("mousedown", start);
    $track.bind("mousedown", drag);
}
```

to:

```
$thumb.bind("mousedown", start);
$track.bind("mousedown", drag);
```

and:

```
else
{
    $(document).bind("mousemove", drag);
    $(document).bind("mouseup", end);
    $thumb.bind("mouseup", end);
    touched = true;
}
```

to:

```
$(document).bind("mousemove", drag);
$(document).bind("mouseup", end);
$thumb.bind("mouseup", end);
touched = true;
```

Hope that is sufficient.

Comment: This was the perfect answer, thanks! Just a note, I tried to make the change in the latest version (2.4.2 I think) but it didn't work. 2.1.8 is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinyscrollbar/d468f8c331e0819d1159ac49ad5b16dcce8f9cb2/lib/jquery.tinyscrollbar.js